# Blocking gaps in loft from the inside

Tags: mice

We have heard scratching in the loft and I have caught two mice. The loft is boarded out pretty much fully and insulated beneath the boarding so it is impossible for me to get to the underneath and I can only put traps down, but I want to prevent anything getting in.
I can check for small holes where visible, I understand they can be tiny like a pencil size and the loft is not exactly tidily finished so that is also going to be impossible. Any thoughts on making mouse free zone?

I also notice that the walls at each end of the roof (adjoining the houses in terrace row) there is then the timber roof but a fair sized gap between the brick and wood - what is best to fill this gap? Lots of wire wool and some form of adhesive? I can't get to the outside as no ladder tall enough so need to try and do this from inside.

Answer (score 1):

Repellants may work here to get a mouse free zone.  If you have a friend with a cat ask them to give you a shoebox of used cat litter from the litter box and tell them to make sure to put as much of the litter the cat has pe ed on in the box.  That is very effective.  Other repellants are peppermint oil, cinnamon, cloves and apple cider vinegar.

Comment: Ok thanks. So do you just leave it in the middle or against a wall and they will go away ? I don't fancy spreading cat littler all around the loft. I hate the fault of them scratching around . Especially this time of year as we keep the kids presents up there and there is all old baby clothes that we wanted to keep, just in recycling bin bags.

Comment: Typically you put the repellant in little cloth bags.  If you use peed on cat litter every 3-6 months you can just go hit the bags with a hammer to break up some of the litter and release fresh scent.